# SAP UI5 BlockLayout - how to setup clickable blocks?

Tags: sapui5

I recently started learning SAP UI5 and got stuck pretty fast. My landing page is built around **BlockLayout control** which contains several blocks with various categories. **Each of these blocks should be clickable** - after the press event, the user is redirected to the subpage with more data.

In the Fiori Design Guidelines, I found this info in the BlockLayout section

> It is also possible to have clickable blocks with their own hover and
>   pressed states.

This is exactly what I need, however, nowhere did I find it explained in more detail. Could someone advise me? How can I setup these clickable blocks in the BlockLayout control? Should I extend the control with Press event or is there some more straightforward way?

Thank you

Comment: You are right - none of the Block* classes have a "press" event. I recommend opening a issue in GitHub for that. https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues

Comment: Thank you, will do that.In the meantime, is there any faster way to make them clickable?

Comment: You can add any clickable control inside your block cells

Comment: OK, will probably do it like that

Comment: BlockLayout Cells can also have links [as titles](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.BlockLayoutLinkTitle/preview) 

`<l:BlockLayoutCell
                               titleAlignment="End"
                               title="End aligned heading">
                <Text text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed diam voluptua."/>
                <l:titleLink>
                               <Link text="This is a title link - wrapping true" href="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/" wrapping="true"/>
                </l:titleLink>
</l:BlockLayoutCell>`

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's been 3 years but I have the solution:
We can attach a browser Event to a determined element using

```js
oElement.attachBrowserEvent("click", function() {
    alert()
})
```

But i made this code to get a array whit all the elements that includes a determined string in their id, this id that is created by sapUi5.

```js
var oElements = this.getView().findElements(true); // Get all elements from the view
var array = [];
// search trhoug the elements of the view a element that the ID includes "cell" (from the original ID: __celln)
oElements.forEach(oElement => {
    if (oElement.sId.includes("cell")) {
        array.push(oElement); // And pushes them into the array
    }
})
// go trhoug all elements of the array attaching the click event
array.forEach(cell => {
    cell.attachBrowserEvent("click", function() {
        alert()
    })
})
```